# regular expression (') vs (,)

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to delete some characters from my string however my regular expression confused between the character (') and (,).
this is my code but it doesn't delete the the (,) character:

```
String str2 = "word,string,phrase";
System.out.println("----- " + str2.replaceAll("\\s+", " ").replaceAll("\\W+^'", " "));
```

How to specify to the regular expression to delete the (,) but not the (').
The example of out put:

> word string phrase

My goal is to delete all the non-word except the character (') like in the word (don't)
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `\W+^'` matches any non-word character one or more times, followed by an assertion to the start of a new line, then the `'` character. Not sure what you're trying to accomplish exactly as you haven't stated your expected output, but based on the input, nothing should change as it doesn't match anything in your string.

Comment: But your expression has a `'` in it, not a `,`.

Comment: Wichi characters you need to remove? If you need only to remove the comma use a simple `replace` instead of `replaceAll`

Comment: Probably you want: `replaceAll("[^\\w']+", " ")`

Comment: Are you trying to replace the commas with newlines? `str2.replace(',', '\n')`.

Comment: Just write what you want to achieve with some examples of input plus expectations.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i updated my question and i added the expected out put

Comment: So, continuing with my previous comment: `str2.replace(',', ' ')`. Sometimes, regex isn't the easiest solution.

Comment: yes i want to delete the comma through the \\w+ and not the '

Comment: Why are you using `\\w+` at all to begin with? As far as we can see, you just need to replace commas. Is there some input cases we're not seeing you cover here? Also, you're not wanting to replace `'`, but you are literally seeking a pattern containing `'` and replacing it with whitespace.

Comment: yes there is other inputs and i have to keep the (') in my strings like in the word (don't) but i have to delete the commas

Comment: @anubhava thank you so much for your suggestion but it is not working for my purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to specify to the regular expression to delete the (,) but not the (').
>
> My goal is to delete all the non-word except the character (') like in the word (don't)

By "delete the (,)" it seems you mean to replace with a space.

By "delete all the non-word" it seems you mean anything matching `\W`, except:

- `'` which should be retained
- `,` which should be replaced with a space

So first, let's find all characters that are **not `\w`, `'`, or `,`**:

```regex
[^\w',]
```

After replacing those with nothing, aka removing them, we can simply replace all `,` with spaces:

```java
str2.replaceAll("[^\\w',]", "").replaceAll(",", " ")
```

That means that any spaces in the original string will be removed too, which is consistent with the described rules, since spaces are non-words.

Comment: Thank you so much for your precious explanation, it works